# Profile based on location(s)

Tags: tasker

I am an independent contractor who has trouble keeping his time sheet up to date.

Is it possible to create a tasker profile or task to do either of the following?

When leaving from this list of locations between a certain time and day of the week, remind me to make a note of what I did (possibly using S Memo).

Between certain times and days of the week, record phone calls from this list of people and note how long the conversation is.

Want to know if this is possible before buying Tasker. Most of these places will have wifi, but a few will not. I have a Samsung Galaxy S4. Have at it. Please let me know and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily achieve the first with Llama, a free app (easier to use than Tasker, its location sending works with cell towers) but for the call recording I think you would need tasker for that (as call recording is not that easy to achieve on android)

Answer (score 0):

Location Based hours tracking has recently become available using the GeoFence technology. I would recommend taking a look at the following apps:

- Time Clock - Automatic Location Based Time Tracker (Made by my team):

  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.timesquared.timetracker
- Hours Tracker - Auto Clock in an Clock out based on GeoFence

  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cribasoft.HoursTrackerFree.Android

But since these apps are more focused on a work log and time sheets, they do not have any features related to call recording.